# Representations of tensor products of algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

For two associative unital algebras $A$ and $B$, defined over $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, is it possible to have an irreducible  representation of $A \otimes_{\mathbb{K}}B$ which is **not** of the form $V \otimes W$, where $V$ is a representation of $A$ and $W$ is a representation of $B$?

Comment: Yes, very easily. For example, $(V \otimes W) \oplus (V \otimes W)$ does not in general factorize as $V' \otimes W'$. Did you want some irreducibility condition?

Comment: Yes, I want irreducibility. I have now written this.

Comment: K=R, A=B=C is a standard example where C/R is any nontrivial field extension.

Comment: @PeterMcNamara Why writing answers in the comment section? (I ask this on MO since 10 years ...)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, when I do something like that, it's because I suspect that the question might change.  For example, probably the question should have been not just about irreducible representations (as @‌MarkWildon [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350483/representations-of-tensor-products-of-algebras#comment878130_350483)) but about *absolutely* irreducible representations (as indicated in @‌Mare's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/350573)).

Answer (score 4):

In case your two algebras $A,B$ are finite dimensional and the field is algebraically closed (or more generally the two algebras are split over the field), then all simple modules over $A \otimes_K B$ are indeed of the form $V \otimes_K W$ for a simple $A$-module $V$ and a simple $B$-module $W$.

This is not true when the algebras are not split: Let $K= \mathbb{R}$ and $A=B=\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Then $A \otimes_K B= \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i) \times \mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i)=\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Thus $A \otimes_K B$ has a simple modules of $K$-dimension two, while all non-zero $A \otimes_K B$-modules of the form $V \otimes_K W$ have $K$-dimension at least 4.

Comment: What does it mean for an algebra to be split?  Isomorphic to a direct power $K^{\oplus n}$?

Comment: Also, note that @PeterMcNamara gave a variant of your counterexample in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350483/representations-of-tensor-products-of-algebras#comment878133_350483).

Comment: @LSpice It means that the algebra modulo its jacobson radical is a products of matrix rings over the field $K$. What you say would be split and basic. Being split is also often called elementary.

Comment: What happens in the infinite dimensional case?